# Нужна ли запятая после "только" и перед "он"?

Tags: пунктуация

*Только что за музыка такая и откуда она звучала он так и не понял.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***(1) Только что за музыка такая и (2) откуда она звучала, (3)он так и не понял.***

Это сложноподчиненное предложение (СПП) с однородными изъяснительными придаточными (1 и 2).

Запятая ставится перед главным предложением (3).

*Что за музыка такая* — это оборот со значением "какая это музыка".

Предложение может иметь такой вид: *Но какая это музыка и откуда она звучала, он так и не понял.*

Comment: А если трактовать "только" не в смысле "не понял только этого", а как элемент главного предложения? (при другом порядке слов было бы: _Только он так и не понял, что за музыка..._)

Comment: Сашко, ты ж на смысл покушаешься! В исходнике ясно: *только что за и откуда*. Зачем переставлять?

Comment: Я не предлагаю переставлять, но предполагаю исходный смысл именно таким .